# Receiving calls over Wi-Fi first

Tags: wi-fi, skype, voip, sip

I just got an android 2.2 prepaid phone (no data plan, so I'm planning to have 3G off). I would like to find some service/android app combination that would let me receive calls over Wi-Fi on Skype or Skype-like app if I'm connected; and then redirect to the phone itself if I'm not. I looked into Google Voice, but it doesn't appear that there is a way to set up an order preference...

Ideally, I'd like to be able to port my old phone number (from my service that I'm about to disconnect) to this service.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: afaik you cannot recieve calls on your phone using the Google Voice app at all.

Comment: @briankb: What are you talking about? I use Google Voice all the time. All of my calls come through GV because that's the only number I give out.

Comment: @Al Right, but the question is regarding "wifi" calls. The *app* doesn't handle calls directly at all. It does not do voip. The gVoice _service_ will route calls to your cellular number. Big difference.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/), an open source PBX.  You can create a dialplan that will ring your Skype or sip address first, and then switch to your prepaid phone number. With version 1.8, [Asterisk supports Google Voice](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google) in addition to Skype. Dialplans are completely configurable, however this does entail setting up a server to run Asterisk. The good news is that the minimum hardware requirements are very low; you can even run it on a consumer router running custom firmware such as DD-WRT, OpenWRT, and Tomato.

A couple places to get you started:

- [Asterisk: The Definitive Guide](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/) - a free book Oreilly book, written for an older version, but still a great primer
- [Asterisk 1.8 documentation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Home)

Comment: It's probably a bit of an overkill solution for just one person. But this would definitely put the control of your phone routing in your hands. Asterisk dialplans are very flexible, and powerful. I'm working on setting one up myself atm.

Answer (score 1):

Android 2.3 natively supports SIP, which means that it's compatible with most VoIP providers. It's as simple as configuring the account at Settings > Call Settings > Internet Accounts. If you cannot upgrade to 2.3, consider trying different SIP clients from the Market (unfortunately I don't have a good recommendation).